# Infopath: Include data for active form only is grayed out

Tags: sharepoint, workflow, infopath

Here's my workflow:

1. An item gets added in a Sharepoint List (Say x). At that moment, a workflow triggers and starts a data collection task. For this task there is an Infopath fom which needs to collect some data from the user
2. This form has some fields which are to be fetched from the corresponding Sharepoint list item in list X and displayed in the form

I am trying to setup a data connection with the list X and fetching the fields of my interest.

However, the option "Include data for active form only" while setting up the connection is grayed out.

I am not able to get the right results in the form from the data connection, the data is not being returned for the right SharepointList item. THe data being returned is for the first item in list X.

Thanks!

Comment: Is the library you are connecting to the same library your form is published to?  You can only use this option for the library your form is published to.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are not passing a filter into the data connection.  You are querying the list without an ID and since you are not selecting a specific list item it is just returning data from the first list item every time.

You are going to need to select a unique identifier and filter your result by clicking the add filter button and setting the foreign key = to primary key in list x.  A quick google search of add filter to data in info path should give you an idea of what I am describing.

You may need to add a column in your initial table that imports the key from list x as a foreign key in your initial list.